# Pasar datos de la store a la data en Vue.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuex, vuetify

quiero saber como puedo pasar datos de la store a variables dentro de la data local. En este caso es para usarlos en gráficas de Echarts.

store (indx.js) - Aquí estoy generando los datos que quiero usar.

```
Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    pruebitaDeStore: [],
    // Valores que requiero pasar
    movil: '2',
    tablet: '4',
    laptop: '8'

  }
})
```

Componente local - Aquí están los datos quemados de forma local y quiero reemplazarlos por los de la store.

```
  data() {
    return {
      option: {

        series: [
          {

            data: [
              // Valores que requiero remplazar
              { itemStyle: { color: "#D94862" }, value: 500, name: "Movil" },
              { itemStyle: { color: "#BDBDBD" }, value: 310, name: "Tablet" },
              { itemStyle: { color: "#2F2740" }, value: 234, name: "Laptop" }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que los stores Vuex son reactivos, la forma más sencilla de "recuperar" un estado es simplemente devolver algún estado del store desde una propiedad computed de tu componente. Por ej: `computed: { movil () { return this.$store.state.movil } }`, luego lo puedes usar en la propiedad data, o donde quieras.

Te dejo un snippet cómo podrías reemplazar el valor de `value` con lo que tienes en el store. Como verás, para mantener la reactividad, pasé lo que tenías en la propiedad `data` a la propiedad `computed` reemplazando el valor hardcodeado por el del store con `this.$store.state.movil`, etc:

```js
new Vue(
    {
        'el': '#app',
        'store': new Vuex.Store(
            {
                state: {
                    movil: '2',
                    tablet: '4',
                    laptop: '8'
                },
            }
        ),
        computed: {
            option() {
                return {
                        series: [
                            {
                                data: [
                                    // Valores que requiero remplazar
                                    { itemStyle: { color: "#D94862" }, value: this.$store.state.movil, name: "Movil" },
                                    { itemStyle: { color: "#BDBDBD" }, value: this.$store.state.tablet, name: "Tablet" },
                                    { itemStyle: { color: "#2F2740" }, value: this.$store.state.laptop, name: "Laptop" }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
            },
        }
    }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/2.1.1/vuex.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <pre>{{option}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola. En este caso estaba usando vuex pero me dista la base para resolverlo, muchas gracias.